# adding the html tag in conditional operator

Tags: php, iframe, drupal-7

I want to use the frame tag with in conditional operator in php want to check the specific field has the value.If yes I want to print the value in frame src.I no want to leave the empty.

```
 <?php print (!empty($fields['field_perspective_video'])) ? 
   echo '<iframe src="'.$fields['field_perspective_video']->content.'"></iframe>'; : ''; ?>
```

In the above line I 'caught unexpected echo' error.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather create a variable and then set it's value inside the if, and then doing an echo to print the variable with or without the iframe:

```
<?php
  $auxVar = '';
  print (!empty($fields['field_perspective_video'])) ? 
  $auxVar = '<iframe src="'.$fields['field_perspective_video']->content.'"></iframe>' : $auxVar = '';
  echo $auxVar;
 ?>
```

Comment: Edited and removed the unexpected symbol, here you can see the code compiles without errors: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba120e347253e09fc34576937e3931cae3322acd

Answer (score 0):

You don't need echo when you already used print

```
print (!empty($fields['field_perspective_video'])) ? 
       '<iframe src="'.$fields['field_perspective_video']->content.'"></iframe>' : '';
```